# Do sharepoint workflows run under different permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

If I fire a sharepoint workflow manually, and it then runs automatically when a document is updated, will these run under the same permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its a declarative workflow then it will fire under the same permissions that the user has.  For instance, let us assume you checked an item into a sharepoint list.  A workflow might exist to send an email to the quality team that a new document was uploaded into the list.  This workflow effectively uses the same permissions as the person who just kicked off that workflow.

Comment: Hmm, that is very interesting.  Is there any chance this could affect whether SPContext.Current get's populated with anything?  I'm running into a situation where when I run my workflow manually it's fine, but if it runs under the situation you described then SPContext.Current is null...

Comment: @Abe Miessler - Absolutely.  A declarative workflow item runs under your account has different permissions then running under say an anon account or an account with less permissions.  This behavior can be changed though.

Comment: VERY interesting.  Can you point me to any links that talk about how to change that behavior?

Comment: I found this question when researching this question:  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1225/running-declarative-workflows-under-system-account